# JS-Clock seems to be paused on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have the following clock code of [JS-Clock](https://github.com/thiago-cavalcanti/JS-Clock):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clock").jsclock('{{date('H:i:s')}}');
});
```

It works fine, but on Google Chrome `63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)` on **Ubuntu 16.04**, when jump to another tab or open another application window i.e blur, the clock seems to be paused.

I tested it with Opera `49.0.2725.64` and it works fine without pause. What's the root cause of this issue and how could I solve it with Chrome, if possible?

Comment: Chrome has a very aggressive "power-save"-function that limit events when the tab is inactive.

Comment: Is there any work around?

Comment: Workarounds: 1: Always have the tab in focus. 2: Don't use Chrome. 3: Use older version of Chrome. 4: Convince Google that you actually want you events to fire even if it is not on an active page. 5: Rewrite your code.